# Верстка. RelativeLayout. Через какой атрибут выровнять по вертикали?

Tags: java, android, вёрстка

Можно ли в `RelativeLayout` выровнять текст *"1 минуту назад"*, относительно кнопки "Поделиться", чтобы текст *"1 минуту назад"* всегда был посередине кнопки, а не вверху, как сейчас.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/one_news_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1 минуту назад"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@color/weak_gray"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/one_news_likes_text"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/one_news_likes_pic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/one_news_share_button"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/one_news_share_button" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/one_news_likes_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="лойс"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/one_news_likes_pic"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/one_news_likes_pic" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/one_news_share_button"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:text="Поделиться"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style_background"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>`
```

Comment: он у вас уже есть : android:layout_centerVertical="true"

Comment: не знала про него. спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для выравнивания в RelativeLayout по вертикали :

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Для выравнивания в RelativeLayout по горизонтали :

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```